# Capistrano deploy assets precompile never compiles assets, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano, asset-pipeline, precompile

**Using deploy.rb to precompile rails assets only when they change, this task is always skipping the compile of my assets :(**

```
namespace :assets do
  task :precompile, :roles => :web, :except => {:no_release => true} do
    from = source.next_revision(current_revision)
    if capture("cd #{latest_release} && #{source.local.log(from)} vendor/assets/ app/assets/ | wc -l").to_i > 0
      run %Q{cd #{latest_release} && #{rake} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} #{asset_env} assets:precompile}
    else
      logger.info "Skipping asset pre-compilation because there were no asset changes"
    end
  end
end
```

What could causing this complete task not compiling? It always thinks there are no asset changes and throws that message.

I also never really understood the task, for example what does below source.log.local refer to?

```
source.local.log
```

Could anyone clarify what the task commands do and has some pointers why it never sees any asset changes? Thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**What it does:**

```
from = source.next_revision(current_revision)
```

`source` is a reference to your source code, as seen through your SCM (git, svn, whatever). This sets `from` as (essentially) the currently deployed version of your source code.

```
capture("cd #{latest_release} && #{source.local.log(from)} vendor/assets/ app/assets/ | wc -l")
```

`capture` means 'execute this command in the shell, and return its output'. The command in question references the log of changes to your source comparing the deployed version to the current version (specifying the paths where assets live as the ones that 'matter'), and passes that into the word count tool (`wc -l`). The `-l` option means that it returns a count of the number of lines in the output. Thus, the output (which is returned by `capture`) is the number of filenames that have changes between these two versions.

If that number is zero, then no files have changed in any of the specified paths, so we skip precompiling.

**Why it doesn't work:**

I don't know. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code itself - it's the same snippet I use, more or less. Here's a couple of things that you can check:

1. Does Capistrano even know you're using the asset pipeline? Check your Capfile. If you don't have `load 'deploy/assets'` in there, deploying won't even consider compiling your assets.
2. Have you, in fact, enabled the asset pipeline? Check application.rb for `config.assets.enabled = true`
3. Do you have incorrect asset paths specified? The code is checking for changes in `vendor/assets/` and `app/assets/`. If your assets live somewhere else (`lib/assets`, for instance), they won't be noticed. (If this is the case, you can just change that line to include the correct paths.
4. Have you, in fact, changed any assets since the last deployment? I recommend bypassing the check for changed assets and forcing precompile to run once, then turning the check back on and seeing it the problem magically resolves itself. In my example, below, setting `force_precompile = true` would do that.

**What I use:**

Here's the version of this I currently use. It may be helpful. Or not. Changes from the original:

1. A more readable way to specify asset paths (if you use it, remember to set `asset_locations` to the places your assets live)
2. An easy way to force precompile to run (set `force_precompile=true` to attempt to run the check, but run precompile regardless)
3. It prints out the count whether or not precompile runs. I appreciate getting some output just to be sure the check is running.
4. If an error occurs when trying to compare the files (as will often happen with brand new projects, for instance), it prints the error but runs precompile anyway.

.

```
  namespace :assets do
    task :precompile, :roles => :web, :except => { :no_release => true } do
      # Check if assets have changed. If not, don't run the precompile task - it takes a long time.
      force_compile = false
      changed_asset_count = 0
      begin
        from = source.next_revision(current_revision)
        asset_locations = 'app/assets/ lib/assets vendor/assets'
        changed_asset_count = capture("cd #{latest_release} && #{source.local.log(from)} #{asset_locations} | wc -l").to_i
      rescue Exception => e
        logger.info "Error: #{e}, forcing precompile"
        force_compile = true
      end
      if changed_asset_count > 0 || force_compile
        logger.info "#{changed_asset_count} assets have changed. Pre-compiling"
        run %Q{cd #{latest_release} && #{rake} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} #{asset_env} assets:precompile}
      else
        logger.info "#{changed_asset_count} assets have changed. Skipping asset pre-compilation"
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: wow, thanks for the super writeup! wow, thx again for providing a better solution with full comments on the way it works, your post feels like a fresh breath of air ;)

Comment: MrTheWalrus: shouldn't `force_compile` be set to `true` in case of error? I'm a bit confused by that bit

Comment: :D thanks for this though, deploying was royal PITA back then.